# Meaning of "all but proven"?

Tags: meaning

I am trying to understand what **"all but proven"** means.

Let's take an example:
*"That shampoo has **all but proven** that it is sustainable."*

Does it means that:

1) That shampoo has been fully proven to be sustainable

2) That shampoo has been proven to be many things except sustainable

3) That shampoo has been proven to be many things including sustainable

4) That shampoo has been proven to be almost sustainable

5) That shampoo has been almost proven to be sustainable

Comment: Most online dictionaries have a specific definition for [***all but***](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/all-but). That's Collins, but here's [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/all%20but) and [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/all-but).

Comment: ...so ***none*** of your suggestions are correct. The meaning is that the shampoo has been ***almost, but not quite*** proven to be sustainable (maybe it's 99.9% certain it's sustainable; all we know is it's not **100%** certain). In case it's not obvious, ***almost proving*** that it's sustainable isn't the same as proving it's ***almost sustainable***.

Comment: I see that you suggest that "all but" with "proven" takes the "almost" meaing of [all but](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/all-but) and not the "except". I added also option (5) as this seems to be what you suggest

Comment: I hope I'm not *suggesting* it! I'm *telling* you what your text means! Looking at it again, I notice that *your* version characterises the shampoo *itself* as the "agent" in the proving process. I guess that's okay - but as you can see, I switched to the passive (with the identity of the "prover" unspecified) in my rephrasings without even realising I'd changed that aspect of the text. Which you *may* take as evidence that I find the passive more "natural" here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Proven* means "demonstrated *without any doubt*". Once a matter has been proven it is accepted as a fact and there is no further debate (at least, that's what you would expect... some people still like to argue).

There can be differing degrees of proof in certain contexts, though. Take a court case for example - a single, clinching piece of *proof* (sometimes called a "smoking gun") may completely settle a case without any need for additional evidence. In other cases, it is the *weight of evidence* that is considered 'proof' - lots of smaller, individual pieces of evidence that could be challenged individually but collectively remove all 'reasonable doubt'.

So, when we say "all but proven" it suggests that the matter *is as good as proven* - perhaps by the *weight of evidence*, rather than a single material fact. I suppose that when it comes to the subject of your quotation, *sustainability*, only time can prove if it is truly sustainable.

Comment: I added option (5). Would you choose 5 then?

Comment: I gave you an up vote, but I'd quibble with your first paragraph. In real life, there's no such thing as absolute 100% proof. That's why in courts they say "proof beyond a reasonable doubt". I heard a lawyer explain this once by saying, "Sure, it's POSSIBLE that invisible Martians ran into the room, killed the victim, thrust the bloody axe into the suspect's hands, and then disappeared just before the witnesses arrived. But ... probably not." ...

Comment: ... Thus, courts today have several "levels" of proof. In a criminal case, the standard is "proof beyond a reasonable doubt". So not really 100%, but like 99%. In civil cases, the standard is "preponderance of evidence". That is, which side is more likely to be right. Like 51%. And in some cases the standard is "clear and convincing evidence", which is a higher standard than "preponderance" but lower than "beyond a reasonable doubt".

Comment: @blupotatos Yes, your #5 would be a fair statement. One might say "almost proven" or "there is strong evidence but I wouldn't quite call it 'proof'".

Comment: @jay No such thing as absolute proof? So, CCTV footage clearly showing someone's face committing a crime would not be absolute proof? At the end of the day, I'm trying to explain English, not the legal system. If I've over-simplified the burden of proof I'd hope that wouldn't affect the effectiveness of the answer

Comment: @Astralbee Maybe the person in the CCTV footage looks like the suspect but is really a different person. Maybe the video is misleading, like it shows the suspect holding the murder weapon but in reality he picked it up after the real murderer had fled the scene.  Maybe the CCTV footage was faked -- I saw a Star Wars movie starring Peter Cushing years after the man had died, the technology exists. Even without the extreme cases, I'm reminded of a news story I saw once about a lawsuit where a reporter secretly filmed a dentist (allegedly) pressuring patients into unnecessary expensive dental ...

Comment: ... work. The reporter said that at the trial, his lawyer showed brief clips from the video where the dentist was telling patients they needed this work. The dentist's lawyer showed brief clips where the dentist gave a balanced presentation. Wouldn't it have been simpler and better, the reporter said, to just show the jury the whole video and let them evaluate it? But that's not how courts work.

Comment: @jay can you prove any of that?

Comment: @Astralbee Absolutely 100%!!